# How to pass credentials from c# client to web api with HttpClient class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i got a similar code whose few area is not clear. so please see the code first.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.Method = "Get";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
//request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//get cookie from Web API
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
{
    Console.Write("Cookie: " + cookieValue.ToString());
    //store in your winform application
}
//get content
string myResponse = "";
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

### why so many code is there related to credentials ?

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
```

what information i need to pass for domain `new`NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

instead of using `HttpWebRequest` how can i achieve the same with `http client` class.

Comment: UseDefaultCredential : using the default credential of logon user https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx and Proxy.Credential is credential for proxy server (if you are using one) and Credential is a credential of your target web server. If your are using HttpClient, then create first HttpClientHandler and put it in constructor from HttpClient.

Comment: suppose my web api is self host in console apps running in pc1 and another console apps send request to web api running in pc2. so tell in my situation which credentials i should use ? should i use 3 credentials as per above code or i just need to use this `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");` ?

Comment: It means, you dont need proxy. Then set Proxy to NULL. Then `UseDefaultCredential=false`, and `request.Credential = new NetworkCredential("userInPc2", "passwordInPc2", "yourDomain");` if you are not in a domain, then just dont set it, use only `request.Credential = new NetworkCredential("userInPc2", "passwordInPc2");`